# python mysql module vs python os module

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, subquery, python-module

Since I am quite new to the Python world, can someone please tell me if it is better to use mysql module to manage mysql tables or is it better to use os module and just write the string that will be the same one that I would use from the Linux Terminal?

I am not sure if mysql module is faster or more efficient, or is it better to use os module, or something else.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use the dedicated library when you can, this is far more adapted. Avoid calling an external process whenever you can (ah, and use subprocess, not os to run a external process)

Comment: First of all thank you for the very fast answer! I just wonder is there a major difference between the two? I mean would my script work much slower or be less efficient if I would use os module instead of mysql module?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons, like being able to manipulate objects, retrieving data as python types, or manage errors... With an external process you'll loose a lot of control over your connection, you'll have to parse the stdout to detect errors or interpret results, for absolutely no gain in terms of perfs or results.

Comment: just to add that recommended way to run shell commands from python script is `subprocess`, not `os`. Check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: It's all relative.  The costly parts tend to be inside the database _server_; the API tends to be less critical to performance.